# Chart.JS Error: this.scale is undefined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying since to days and really new to Chart.js. Everything seems to be clear but now i would like to put a label on top of every single bar.
Trying this i get an error: *this.scale is undefined*. I got the *animation.onComplete* Snippet out of the net but it seems i make a mistake. The Chart works fine .. i just don't get the labels on top of the bars. Maybe someone can please help me with this ?! 
I also have a line chart with the same problem.

```
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chartA").getContext("2d");

            Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 2400;
            Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = "easeInOutQuad";
            Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 4;
            Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 5;
            Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hitRadius = 1;

            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "bar",
                data: {
                    labels: ["A","B","C"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Test",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                        borderColor: "#CF2748",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [10,20,30]
                    }]
                },                  
                options: {
                    tooltips: { mode: 'nearest', intersect: false },
                    layout: { padding: { left: 20, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 } },
                    legend: { display: true, position: 'top' },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: { maxTicksLimit: 9, stepSize: 300, callback: function(value, index, values) { return value+" €"; } }                             
                        }]
                    },
                    animation: {
                        onComplete: function () {
                            var ctx = this.chart.ctx; // this part doesn't work
                            ctx.font = this.scale.font;
                            ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor;
                            ctx.textAlign = "center";
                            ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

                            this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                                dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                                    ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thank you so much
Oliver

---

Thanks @Jeff I was testing around and get closer.

```
chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    dataset.data.forEach(function (value) {
        ctx.fillText(value, x, y);
    });
});
```

Now i have in "value" the right value. But i need to refer X and Y. Where do i get them? If i change X and Y with static value it works but all values were logically printed on the same space.

Comment: Did you try replacing `this.scale.font` with `chart.scale.font`? Use `chart` instead of `this`.

Comment: Hello Jeff Yeah i tried this. Then the error is called chart.scaled is undefined

Comment: How about removing the `this.chart.`ctx and just using the `ctx`  since it is being passed in as a parameter.

Comment: It's passing the scale-line but now hang on 'this.datasets is undefined'. I tried to delete this and change it to chart or ctx .. but nothing

Comment: Is `this.data.datasets` defined?

Comment: are you trying to put labels (A, B, C) or values (10, 20, 30) ?

Comment: I would like to have the value of every single bar on top of the bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

You could rather use the following chart plugin to accomplish the same :

```
Chart.plugins.register({
   afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, datasetIndex) {
         var datasetMeta = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex);
         datasetMeta.data.forEach(function(meta) {
            var posX = meta._model.x;
            var posY = meta._model.y;
            var value = chart.data.datasets[meta._datasetIndex].data[meta._index];
            // draw values
            ctx.save();
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.font = '16px Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText(value, posX, posY);
            ctx.restore();
         });
      });
   }
});
```

<sup>add this plugin at the beginning of your script.</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, datasetIndex) {
         var datasetMeta = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex);
         datasetMeta.data.forEach(function(meta) {
            var posX = meta._model.x;
            var posY = meta._model.y;
            var value = chart.data.datasets[meta._datasetIndex].data[meta._index];
            // draw values
            ctx.save();
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.font = '16px Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText(value, posX, posY);
            ctx.restore();
         });
      });
   }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("chartA").getContext("2d");

Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 2400;
Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = "easeInOutQuad";
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 4;
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 5;
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hitRadius = 1;

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: "bar",
   data: {
      labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
      datasets: [{
         label: "Test",
         backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
         borderColor: "#CF2748",
         borderWidth: 1,
         data: [10, 20, 30]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'nearest',
         intersect: false
      },
      layout: {
         padding: {
            left: 20,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
         }
      },
      legend: {
         display: true,
         position: 'top'
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               maxTicksLimit: 9,
               stepSize: 300,
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return value + " €";
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartA"></canvas>
```

Comment: My hero of the day :-) Thank you for all the help

Comment: Hey .. just another question to your plugin. Is there a possibility to change visibility in Bar chart = yes and i.e. in Line Chart = no ? How can i differentiate between those 2 charts ?

Comment: You can get chart type using `chart.config.type`. So to make visibility only for bar chart add - `if (chart.config.type !== 'bar') return` at he beginning of  `afterDatasetsDraw` function.